# Reversed direction modulo operator?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

This: `i = ((i + 1) % itemArray.length` assigns to `i` the next space going towards the right in a circular manner.

Is there a way I can make `i` go in a circular manner, but towards the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep; replace $(i+1)$ with $(i-1)$. IF your language has a screwy modulo operator for negative numbers, you might have to use

```
i = ((i + (itemArray.length - 1)) % itemArray.length
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation of the % operator; if it’s implemented sensibly, you can simply replace $i+1$ by $i-1$. Check to see whether `-1 % 5` returns $-1$ or $4$. If it returns $4$, you’re in good shape. Otherwise, replace $i+1$ by `i - 1 + itemArray.length` if you don’t want to consider separate cases.

Basically you want to hope that the implementation does not use *truncated division* as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).